# Draw rectangle over optical flow feature points

Tags: c, opencv

I want to draw a rectangle over feature points get from optical flow process. 
I'm using cvSeqPush method to draw it:

```
CvSeq* trackCarContour = cvCreateSeq(CV_32FC2, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint2D32f), contour_storage );
for(int i=0;i<numberOfFeaturesFound;i++)
{
    cvSeqPush( trackCarContour, &cur_feature[i] );
}
CvRect trackCarRect = cvBoundingRect(trackCarContour, 0);
```

However, the rectangle drawn is not bound over those points, instead it shows on the top left corner of the image.

Is there any other way to do this? Or, what's wrong with my way of doing this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want a single rectangle enclosing all points, or a rectangle enclosing each point? Can you post the current code you have?

Comment: i want to have a rectangle to enclose all the feature points found.
                                                                      
CvSeq* trackCarContour = cvCreateSeq(CV_32FC2, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint2D32f), contour_storage );
for(int i=0;i<numberOfFeaturesFound;i++) 
{
 cvSeqPush( trackCarContour, &cur_feature[i] );
} 
 CvRect trackCarRect = cvBoundingRecttrackCarContour, 0);